# Update JComponent to reflect an object change

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I have a series of JLabels within an interface which are used to display the properties of an object. Is it possible to update the JComponents automatically if said object is replaced by another of the same class? Would such a method be considered bad practice? For example consider the following:

```
String stringToBeDisplayed = new String("String 1");
JLabel label = new JLabel(stringToBeDisplayed);
stringToBeDisplayed = new String("String 2");
//*Refresh label to show string change*
```

I know that the text of the JLabel could be set using JLabel.setText() or the label could be replaced, but I am lazy and these methods are a little inconvenient with many JComponents!

Comment: the observer-pattern will help you achieve your goal

Comment: `new String("String 1")` is obsolete. Just use `"String 1"`. The same applies to `new String("String 2")`, just use `"String 2"` instead.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was trying to emphasise the fact that stringToBeDisplayed could be any object, not necessarily text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do will not even work, because re-initializing `stringToBeDisplayed` will not affect anything you have passed it to--in this case, the `JLabel()` constructor.

The way to do what you want *is* to call `JLabel.setText()`.  If you have a lot of components, you must make a lot of calls.  You might be able to wrap some of them so you can call one of your methods to update many of them with a batch, but it's the way you'll have to do it.  You might also be able to reduce your typing by putting your `JLabel`s in `Collection`s or arrays and using loops.

Although, *in theory*, you could subclass or composite `JLabel` and add a method that accepts some `String`-wrapping object that you would have to write the class for, and then you could have that class accept change listeners (an Observer pattern) and upon a change update the `JLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but you make a basic java error. Strings are immutable in java. You have passed the String object "String 1" to the JLabel. The JLabel has no 'pointer' to stringToBeDisplayed, so assigning another String object to the variable stringToBeDisplayed will just not work.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not do this.

Imagine a variable as a box. The box "stringToBeDisplayed" contains the string. setText() takes the box and pours the content to another box - the text inside the label - due to the fact that it is a computer science box, "stringToBeDisplayed" is still filled (metaphors just never work all the way through).

Now you put something new to the "stringToBeDisplayed" box. How is the other box supposed to know about this?

You may want to have a look at the Observer Pattern or Model-View-Control.

Comment: Ah, thats what I feared. Would there be no way for them to share the same box?